# How do I get a Jumbotron img to resize with the screen?

Tags: html, image, css

I'm making a little project-school website with x10Host, and I am writing my own custom HTML for it. The front page is going to have a little image explaining who I am and what I do. This is the image:

[image: image I am trying to get to show up]

When I use the following HTML and CSS, it shows up perfectly (image shows):

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="Jumbotron.png"></img>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron{
    position:relative;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    top:-50px;
    left:-50px;
}
.jumbotron img{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

It shows up perfectly as this:

[image: jumbotron as seen on the website]

The only problem I am having is when I resize the window. Currently, the window is 1080p. If I resize it, this happens:

[image: resized website]

Is there any way I could modify the HTML or CSS to make the image resize to the client's screen? If you would like to see the full HTML code, the website is http://mrsquer.x10Host.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.jumbotron{
            margin-left:-10px;
            margin-top:-10px;
            height:100%;
            min-width:100%;
            position:absolute;    
        }
        .jumbotron img{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            max-width:100%;
        }
```

try this for css

Comment: That worked, but the position had to be relative, not absolute. Thanks.

Comment: your welcome,if u add to css      html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
} so u dont need also margin-left and margin top so u should delete them  and change to position to relative example https://jsfiddle.net/Ljdxnwot/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `max-width: 100%; height:100%;` to limit it to the container's width but keep max image height.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <title>css testing</title>
            <style type = "text/css">
                .jumbotron
                {
                    position:relative;
                    width:100%;
                                            max-width: 100%;
                    height:100%;
                }

                .jumbotron img
                {
                    width:100%;
                    height: auto;
                }
            </style>

            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <img src="Jumbotron.png"></img>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

img height must be set to 'auto' or it will not scale correctly (as in code above).

This works for any size screen, but I wouldn't use it.

Setting the img as a background would give you more freedom to add content.  And

```
height: 100%;
```

is not needed unless you want the entire screen occupied by the container div.

If you want a DIY site, maybe read-up on basic html and css.  Have fun !